# How to copy data into Excel range formatted as table and not lose table formatting

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Does anyone know how to copy data into Excel via C# into a table range and not lose the table formatting?

Everytime I copy data to the range, it loses the formatting that was set previously.

```
private object[,] Get2DArrayData()
    {
        var obj = new object[2, 4];
        obj[0, 0] = "Header1";
        obj[0, 1] = "Header2";
        obj[0, 2] = "Header3";
        obj[0, 3] = "Header4";
        obj[1, 0] = 1;
        obj[1, 1] = 2;
        obj[1, 2] = 3;
        obj[1, 3] = 4;
        return obj;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        Range range = worksheet.Range["A1:D2"];
        Excel.ListObject obj = worksheet.ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, null, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, null);
        obj.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium3";
        obj.Name = "MyTableNamedRange";
        //table style is lost after setting Value2 on the range
        range.Value2 = Get2DArrayData();
    }
```

Everytime I paste the array data to Value2, the ListObject gets cleared. Is there any way to not lose this formatting? Setting the Value2 property before adding to the ListObjects property isn't possible.

Comment: I think you need to expand your code a little here.

Comment: again, too little code to see whats going on. You need to provide enough information that we can see whats going on. We have no idea what `Get2DArrayData()` does, or what Value2 is within your range object. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then update your question a bit more so we can help

Comment: Get2DArrayData is unimportant in this case. It simply returns a multidimensional object array (ie. object[,]) and assigns to Value2 on the range object.

Comment: There still isnt enough information present for us to see whats happening. Please supply more.

Comment: What else do you need?

Comment: Not your complete code, but expand on what you have submitted. you need to provide enough for us to see the process of things so try and identify what isnt working. From what you have posted, i can't see anything wrong - but you say there is.

Comment: See revised code above. This should be runnable within a simple ExcelAddin VSTO project. You'll see that the table formatting is wiped when Value2 is set. If you move the set of Value2 to before the formatting then its obviously retained. Is there any way to stop the formatting from being cleared when setting Value2 or should I be using some other way to paste the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the ListObject with data, you should set the ListObject's HeaderRowRange and DataBodyRange to the content array:

```
obj.HeaderRowRange.Value2 = /* Your array with table headers goes here */
obj.DataBodyRange.Value2 = /* Your array with table data goes here */
```